# 'module' has no attribute 'translateX' error in Maya

Tags: python, random, scripting, maya, mel

I have just recently started writing Python code to be used in Maya.

My code looks like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds;
import random as rand;
for x in range (0,10):
    cmds.polyCube(cmds.translateX == rand(0,100));
    x += 1;
```

Maya then gives the error, 'module' has no attribute 'translateX'

I am not sure what is going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`translateX` isn't a command or part of the argument for a polyCube.

What you want is something more like

```
import maya.cmds as cmds;
import random as rand;
for x in range (10):
    # create the cube at origin
    cmds.polyCube()
    # move it to a random X
    cmds.xform( t = (rand.randrange(0,100), 0, 0) )
```

When you create the polyCube it will be selected, so issuing the `xform()` immediately afterward will only affect the most recently created cube.  You could also use `cmds.setAttr(".translateX" = rand(0,100))` but that's less flexible if you also want to set the Y or Z directions